# ngRepeat not updating after ajax call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, model-view-controller

This is part of my view:

```
<div class="chartspanel">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, chartData) in main.chartsData" class="chart-box">
        <div class="ibox">
            <div class="ibox-title">
                <h3>{{key}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-content" chart="chartData" chart-name="key"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

now, my controller:

```
class DashboardCtrl {
  constructor ($scope, $timeout, $sce, $rootScope, ChartService) {
    "ngInject";

    this.$sce = $sce;
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
    this.$timeout = $timeout;
    this.chartsData = null;
    this.chartService = ChartService;

    this.loadChartsEvent(this.$scope, this.$timeout, this.chartsData);
  }

  loadChartsEvent (scope, timeout, chartsData) {
      this.$rootScope.$on('loadCharts', (event, data) => {
          timeout(() => {
              scope.$apply(() => {
                  chartsData = data;
                  console.log(chartsData);
              });
          });
      });
  }
}
```

Data is retrieved from directive using $brodcast, this part is working fine, but after i'm trying to update `chartsData` in my view ng-repeat is not acting at all, i still have the same commented `<!-- ngRepeat: (key, chartData) in main.chartsData -->`. Why is that, console log shows proper data from ajax call... Can anybody help?

Comment: why do you do that reassignments? 1) you don't need to pass such parameters like `$scope`, `$timeout` etc. to `localChartsEvent`, they are accessible from all over `DashboardCtrl` class. 2) you don't need `$scope.apply` inside `$timeout`, it is already there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have `chartsData = data`, all you are doing is changing the object that the local variable `chartsData` points to. This does not change the actual property that the view is bound to, which is the `chartsData` property on the controller instance, accessed via `this.chartsData`.

You do need to set `this.chartsData = data` for it to work, and your code can be dramatically simplified to remove the redundant `$timeout` and `$scope.$apply()` calls.

Comment: jizzz, i don't know why but i've got undefined previously, maybe some typo issue, but bc of that i thought that this is local scope and this props is not passing through controller constructor, it's working fine right now, much thx @GregL

Comment: As a guess, you may not have been using arrow functions before, or you just passed a function like `this.loadChartsEvent`, which will not have the correct value of `this`. It's a common JS gotcha.

Comment: No, i'm using it a while now but i've tried some many ways to track this issue that i've dozens thoughts about it, anyway thank you for your help, cheers and calm night/day

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your `loadChartsEvent` to use the `this` keyword when assigning to the `chartsData` property, and add a timeout value of `0` in your `timeout` function to move your call to the end of the stack, your code will become like this:

```
loadChartsEvent(scope, timeout, chartsData) {
  this.$rootScope.$on('loadCharts', (event, data) => {
      timeout(() => {
          scope.$apply(() => {
              this.chartsData = data;
              console.log(chartsData);
          });
      }, 0);
  });
}
```

Comment: The `0` value is implicit, it will not change the behaviour at all. [0 is the default value](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/timeout.js#L32).

Comment: Thanks for this info :)